# Extract thumbnail from raw picture via http url

Tags: python

With `rawpy`, I can [extract an embedded preview](https://letmaik.github.io/rawpy/api/rawpy.RawPy.html#rawpy.RawPy.extract_thumb) from a raw picture:

```py
import rawpy
with rawpy.imread('image.nef') as raw:
    thumb = raw.extract_thumb()
```

However, this needs to read the whole image before it can extract the preview.

But I want to read from the internet, so this needs to download 30MB to save 1-2 MB of preview image. This is very slow and I want to speed things up.

---

I tried this:

```py
import requests
import rawpy

data = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with rawpy.imread(data.raw) as raw:
    thumb = raw.extract_thumb()
```

Q: How can I download a raw picture from a url only until `rawpy` can extract the thumbnail?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `requests.iter_content()` to get the file by chunks, and then just `try` to `extract_thumb()` on the concatenation of the chunks and `break` on success:

```py
import requests
import rawpy
import io

r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

file = b''
for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024000):
    file = file + chunk
    try:
        with rawpy.imread(io.BytesIO(file)) as raw:
            thumb = raw.extract_thumb()
            break
    except rawpy._rawpy.LibRawIOError:
        continue
```